# Why do I get this error when I import CCXT and flask together? [TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed]

Tags: python, flask, ccxt

Why do I get error when I import CCXT and flask together?

```
    import ccxt
    from flask import Flask
    
    exchange = ccxt.coinbase()
    markets = exchange.load_markets()
    
    for market in markets:
        print(market)
```

**OUTPUT:**

> Exception ignored in: <function Exchange.**del** at
> 0x000001D30B3B2D30> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\ccxt\base\exchange.py",
> line 399, in **del**   File
> "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
> line 747, in close   File
> "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
> line 325, in close   File
> "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py",
> line 222, in clear   File
> "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3_collections.py",
> line 100, in clear   File
> "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py",
> line 173, in    File
> "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 494, in close TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit
> from BaseException is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

the new update of ccxt has solved this issue.

Comment: Can you specify the version so this answer remains useful for future readers?